# A function doesn't respond in ref.on() even if the result is correct

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to create an app named workspace. I had asked another question earlier but now the features I have added are more. There is a remarks system. I have tried using different versions of my code and the code I have given has the best version I created. I cannot find an answer to my question on the net so I had to ask it here.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref(); 

function stdRemarks(studentName){
    let finalStuff;
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
        let keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()][studentName]['remarks']);
        for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            let objectToDealWith = snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()][studentName]['remarks'];
            let remark = objectToDealWith[keys[i]]['remark'];
            let examiner = objectToDealWith[keys[i]]['examiner'];
            let fullRemark = ` ${examiner}: ${remark} | `
            finalStuff +=  fullRemark;
        }
        return finalStuff;
    });
}

ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
     let dashTab = document.getElementById("dashboard_table");
     let btn = document.getElementById("csv_blob");
     let btn2 = document.getElementById("json_view");
     let btn3 = document.getElementById("json_export");
     btn.style.display = "block";
     btn2.style.display = "block";
     $("#json_export").css('display', 'block');
     dashTab.innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Class</th><th>Email</th><th>Subject</th><th>Project Info</th><th>Remarks</th><th>Project</th><th style='display: none;'>Project Download URL</th><th>Add Remark</th></tr></thead>";
     let jsonRecieved = snapshot.val();
     let objectToDealWith = snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()];
     let lengthOfIt = Object.size(objectToDealWith);
     for(i=0;i<lengthOfIt;i++){
        let int = i + 1;
        let names = Object.keys(objectToDealWith);
        let stdName = names[i];
        let finalResult = objectToDealWith[stdName];
        document.getElementById("schoolnameis").innerText = "Dashboard - " + objectToDealWith['i'];
        let stdClass = finalResult['class'];
        let stdEmail = finalResult['email'];
        let stdSubject = finalResult['subject'];
        let stdiName = finalResult['stdname'];
        let stdProjectName = finalResult['projectname']
        let stdProjectInfo = finalResult['projectinfo'];
        let stdProjectLink = finalResult['projectlink'];
        console.log(stdRemarks(stdiName))
        let elementToPush = `<tr><td>${stdiName.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td>${stdClass.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td>${stdEmail.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td>${stdSubject.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td>${stdProjectInfo.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td>${stdRemarks(stdnameName).replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td><a href=${stdProjectLink}>${stdProjectName.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</a></td><td style='display:none;'>${stdProjectLink}</td><td id="${stdName}" style='text-align:center;' onclick="closeThatSomeThing();getIdOfTd(this.id)">&#x2795</td></tr>`;
        dashTab.innerHTML += elementToPush;
     }
});
```

So everything is working fine but some stuff here seems to corrupt the whole code. My database looks somewhat like this 
[image: Have look]

Here is the error.

```
//A warning by firebase.
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

//An error occuring on the variable `elementToPush` and its part ${stdRemarks(stdnameName).replace(/undefined/g, '') in the code.
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I have to submit this project tomorrow.

Comment: I edited the code. It works now but it does not loop for all the entries. I used the code inside the ref.on and it works for just 1 entry... [Here is the code](https://hastebin.com/ezicitoxaw.js). Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

your function 'stdRemarks' has a return type of 'void'.  either return the the complete ref.on() or move 'finalstuff' outside the .on() function call and make sure the function 'stdRemarks' has the desired return type. in this case this would be a 'string';

```
function stdRemarks(studentName){
    let finalStuff = "";
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
        let keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()][studentName]['remarks']);
        for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            let objectToDealWith = snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()][studentName]['remarks'];
            let remark = objectToDealWith[keys[i]]['remark'];
            let examiner = objectToDealWith[keys[i]]['examiner'];
            let fullRemark = ` ${examiner}: ${remark} | `
            finalStuff +=  fullRemark;
        }
    });
     return finalStuff;
}
```

Comment: this will fix the error caused by trying to .replace() on something that is undefined. I don't knows how firebase or its functions works....

Comment: this dosent work. Still gives me the error that .replace isnt defined. According to the datatype js will automatically make it a string or a int. And it still returns that thing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using this code.

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
     let dashTab = document.getElementById("dashboard_table");
     let btn = document.getElementById("csv_blob");
     let btn2 = document.getElementById("json_view");
     let btn3 = document.getElementById("json_export");
     btn.style.display = "block";
     btn2.style.display = "block";
     $("#json_export").css('display', 'block');
     dashTab.innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Class</th><th>Email</th><th>Subject</th><th>Project Info</th><th>Remarks</th><th>Project</th><th style='display: none;'>Project Download URL</th><th>Add Remark</th></tr></thead>";
     let jsonRecieved = snapshot.val();
     let objectToDealWith = snapshot.val().schools[returnCurrentUser()];
     let lengthOfIt = Object.size(objectToDealWith)-1;
     for(i=0;i<lengthOfIt;i++){
        let finalRemark;
        let int = i + 1;
        let names = Object.keys(objectToDealWith);
        let stdName = names[i];
        let finalResult = objectToDealWith[stdName];
        let stdClass = finalResult['class'];
        let stdEmail = finalResult['email'];
        let stdSubject = finalResult['subject'];
        let stdiName = finalResult['stdname'];
        for(var e=0;e<Object.size(objectToDealWith[stdName]['remarks']);e++){
            let keys = Object.keys(objectToDealWith[stdName]['remarks']);

            let remark = objectToDealWith[stdName]['remarks'][keys[e]]['remark'];
            let examiner =  objectToDealWith[stdName]['remarks'][keys[e]]['examiner'];
            let completeRemark = ` | ${examiner} : ${remark}  `
            finalRemark += completeRemark;
        }

        let stdProjectName = finalResult['projectname']
        let stdProjectInfo = finalResult['projectinfo'];
        let stdProjectLink = finalResult['projectlink'];
        let elementToPush = `<tr><td>${stdiName}</td><td>${stdClass}</td><td>${stdEmail}</td><td>${stdSubject}</td><td>${stdProjectInfo}</td><td>${finalRemark.replace(/undefined/g, '')}</td><td><a href=${stdProjectLink}>${stdProjectName}</a></td><td style='display:none;'>${stdProjectLink}</td><td id="${stdName}" style='text-align:center;' onclick="closeThatSomeThing();getIdOfTd(this.id)">&#x2795</td></tr>`;
        dashTab.innerHTML += elementToPush;
     }
});
```

What i did here was that i turned i to e in the second loop and it worked...